# Populate multiple datatables from DataReader. Is it even possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datareader

I have a stored procedure which returns two resultsets which i capture in a DataReader.

```
dr = returnData(Id,frmDate, toDate);

dt1 = new DataTable();
dt2 = new DataTable();

dt1.Load(dr);
dr.NextResult(); // Proceed to next resultset
dt2.Load(dr);
```

DataTable dt1 gets successfully populated but DataTable dt2 remains empty.
How to do it. Is it even possible ? Does DataReader get destroyed the first time it is used ?

Comment: `NextResult()` should do the trick. Can you possibly show us the SPROC which is being called?

Comment: The stored procedure is successfully returning two resultsets , I have checked by executing directly on Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: Does `NextResult` actually return `true`? The code you've shown ignores the return value.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok , so I checked with `if(dr.NextResult())`...it is returning false..even though there are two resultsets

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders .. ok, will take care from next time..

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969318/multiples-table-in-datareader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very old question, but in case someone else stumbles upon this... Found the answer in [this SO answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969548/1086134) If you use `DataTable.Load()` then you should not use `rdr.NextResult()`, as that is taken care implicitly. Simply call `.Load()` for your next table. So, for example, if you have an `expectedTableCount`:

```
ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add("Table1");
ds.Tables[0].Load(reader);
for (int ii = 1; ii < expectedTableCount; ii++)
{
    ds.Tables.Add("Table" + (ii + 1));
    ds.Tables[ii].Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-6.0 Under the second "Remarks" section: `The Load method consumes the first result set from the loaded IDataReader, and after successful completion, sets the reader's position to the next result set, if any.` Instead of a for loop, I might recommend a `do...while (!reader.IsClosed)`