# Getiing multiple resultset from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a stored procedure that contains multiple selects a bit like this:

```
select 'Connected'
exec DoWork
  @var1 = 23,
  @var2 = 400
select 'Done'
select 'Bye'
```

When I call the stored procedure from my C# code I only get a single result in my `SqlDataReader` and it is the 'Connected' select.

I call it like this

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "SP_MyProc";
command.Parameters.Add("@val", "TEST");
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
       temp += reader.GetString(i) + " ";
    }

    worker.ReportProgress(0, temp);
}

connection.Close();
```

It makes sense that normally a stored procedure only returns a single result set, however I need this for debugging purposes. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Check this out.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969318/multiples-table-in-datareader

Comment: okay as suggested here is the comment instead of answer.  use the SqlDataReader.NextResult method :)

Comment: @ZedBee: your answer was perfect as an answer.  Some people just don't understand that you can not classify a response as an answer or comment simply by the length of the text.  Some answers do not require lengthy explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the SqlDataReader [NextResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This is more of a comment!